# set active artboard by name in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, illustrator-scripting

There is `getActiveArtboardIndex` and `setActiveArtboardIndex`, I can get the `Artboard` object with `getByName`.

But how do I **set active artboard by name**?

Or at least get index from the `Artboard` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but still solves the problem:

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var ABName = "Artboard Name";
function setActiveArtboardBy(name) {
    var artboard = docRef.artboards.getByName(name);
    for (i = 0; i < docRef.artboards.length; i++) {
        if (docRef.artboards[i] == artboard) {
            docRef.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
setActiveArtboardBy(ABName);
```

Comment: Please explaine what this piece of code does. Only presenting the code kicks off all reader not able to unstand what you did ...

Comment: Kurt, it takes artboard object by given name, then goes through all artboard comparing with it. When it figures out the right one it sets it as active and breaks the cycle. That is what this function does.